# $L^2$ function on finite interval implies $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppse $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an $L^2$ function on the finite interval $(a,b)$. That is, $$\int_{a}^b|f(x)|^2dx<\infty$$ Is it always true that $f$ is an $L^1$ function on the same interval, that is, $$\int_{a}^b|f(x)|dx<\infty \text{ }?$$

Comment: The symmetry is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that the interval has finite length.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: And now, if you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $\int_a^b 1\cdot\lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx$, what do you get?

Comment: That will be $\left(\int_a^b|f(x)|dx\right)^2\leq \int_a^b1dx\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx=(b-a)\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx$, hence the conclusion.

Comment: Nice! Without having the idea that I should use Cauchy-Schwarz, this is not easy at all!

Comment: Yep. The same (with the obvious necessary modifications) holds for every measure space of finite measure.

Comment: Oh, and if you use Hölder's inequality, you have $L^p \subset L^q$ for every $p \geqslant q$ on a finite measure space.

Comment: A more elementary method is to consider the set $A=\{ x :|f(x)|<1\}$ and write $\int |f|=\int_A|f|+\int_{A^C}|f|$. Note on $A^C$, $|f|\le|f|^2$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, every square integrable function on a finite interval is integrable. Even more generally, if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a finite measure space ($\mu(X) < \infty$), then for all $1 \leqslant q < p \leqslant \infty$ we have $L^p(\mu) \subset L^q(\mu)$.

Hölder's inequality states that for $r,s \geqslant 1$ with $\frac1r + \frac1s = 1$, and any measurable $u,v$, we have

$$\int_X \lvert u(x)v(x)\rvert\,d\mu \leqslant \left(\int_X \lvert u(x)\rvert^r\right)^{1/r}\cdot \left(\int_X \lvert v(x)\rvert^s\right)^{1/s}.$$

Applying that with $u = 1$, $v = \lvert f\rvert^q$, $s = \frac{p}{q}$ and $r = \frac{p}{p-q}$ yields

$$\lVert f\rVert_q^q \leqslant \mu(X)^{1-q/p}\cdot \lVert f\rVert_p^{q},$$

or

$$\lVert f\rVert_q \leqslant \mu(X)^{1/q-1/p}\cdot \lVert f\rVert_p.$$

So $\lVert f\rVert_p < \infty$ implies $\lVert f\rVert_q < \infty$ for $q < p$ if $\mu(X) < \infty$.

Comment: Adding related question about whether it is possible to remove the finite measure assumption: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774463/removing-finite-measure-assumption-in-the-proof-that-⊂-where-1⩽

Comment: Does this also hold in case $\mu(X) = \infty$, which is in case of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ ?