# Removing Finite Measure Assumption in the Proof that ()⊂() where 1⩽<<∞

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

Looking at this question and the corresponding answer from @DanielFischer:

[$L^2$ function on finite interval implies $L^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561140/l2-function-on-finite-interval-implies-l1/4774190#4774190)

I was trying to see if we really need the finite measure assumption ($\mu(X) < \infty$).

What I have tried so far:

Trying to see if a more general property can be derived. That is, if $\left(X,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$
is a positive measure space (not necessarily finite), then for all $1\leqslant q<p<\infty$
we have $L^{p}\left(\mu\right)\subset L^{q}\left(\mu\right)$.

We are given that for any measurable function $u\in L^{p}\left(\mu\right)$
the following holds

\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{p}=\left\{ \int_{X}\left|u\right|^{p}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty
\end{equation}
Hölder's inequality states that for $s,t\geqslant1$ with $\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{t}=1$,
and any measurable functions $f,g$, we have

\begin{equation}
\int_{X}fg\,\operatorname{d}\mu\leqslant\left\{ \int_{X}f^{s}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{1}{s}}\left\{ \int_{X}g^{t}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{1}{t}}
\end{equation}
Now we can write $p=q+r$. Here, $r<p$. This means $1=\frac{q}{p}+\frac{r}{p}$.

We can write,
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{q}\,\operatorname{d}\mu=\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{p}\left|u\right|^{-r}\,\operatorname{d}\mu
\end{equation}
Applying Holder's inequality using $s=\frac{p}{q}\geqslant1$ and
$t=\frac{p}{r}\geqslant1$ gives,
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{q}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\leqslant\left\{ \int_{X}\left(\left|u\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{q}{p}}\left\{ \int_{X}\left(\left|u\right|^{-r}\right)^{\frac{p}{r}}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{r}{p}}
\end{equation}
Put $f=\left|u\right|^{\frac{p}{q}}$, $g=\frac{1}{\left|u\right|}=\left|u\right|^{-1}$.

Note that $f=\left|u\right|^{\frac{p}{q}}$, $g=\frac{1}{\left|u\right|}=\left|u\right|^{-1}$ are measurable using the following property: Continuos Composite Function of a Measurable function is a measurable function - { Theorem 1.7 in Rudin Real and Complex Analysis;
[Papa Rudin theorem 1.7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519181/papa-rudin-theorem-1-7) ;
[Measurable function raised to a power still a measurable funktion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432640/measurable-function-raised-to-a-power-still-a-measurable-funktion) ; [$f$ measurable implies $\dfrac{1}{f}$ measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718964/f-measurable-implies-dfrac1f-measurable) }.

This gives,
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{q}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\leqslant\left\{ \int_{X}\left(f\right)^{p}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{q}{p}}\left\{ \int_{X}\left(g\right)^{p}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{r}{p}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{q}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\leqslant\left[\left\{ \int_{X}\left(f\right)^{p}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{1}{p}}\right]^{q}\left[\left\{ \int_{X}\left(g\right)^{p}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\right\} ^{\frac{1}{p}}\right]^{r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{q}^{q}=\int_{X}\left|u\right|^{q}\,\operatorname{d}\mu\leqslant{\lVert f\rVert_{p}^{q}}\lVert g\rVert_{p}^{r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{q}\leqslant{\lVert f\rVert_{p}}\lVert g\rVert_{p}^{\frac{r}{q}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lVert u\rVert_{q}<\infty
\end{equation}

There is a mistake here as pointed out by (Dominik Kutek)  since the functions $f,g$ might not have finite $p$ norm.

That is $\lVert f\rVert_{q}$ and$\lVert g\rVert_{q}$ can be infinite. Especially with $$ it's easy to see, since if $g()= \frac{1}{(1+^2)}$ on $(0,∞)$ with Lebesgue measure, then it's in every $L^{p};≥1$, but $()=1+^2$ fails to be integrable.

Is there is some way to fix the above mistake or an alternate approach to show that $L^{p}\left(\mu\right)\subset L^{q}\left(\mu\right)$ without using the finite measure assumption?

Is this true also for the case when $p=\infty$.  This is for the essential supremum case or the members of $L^{\infty}\left(\mu\right)$, which are the essentially bounded measurable functions on $\left(X,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$.

Comment: Consider the functions $x^{-\frac{1}{q}}\chi_{[1,\infty)}$, which are in $L^p$ for all $p>q$ but not $L^q$.

Comment: @MW Thanks, this is a helpful suggestion. Though, it is restrictive (perhaps, more?) than the finite measure assumption since we are limiting the class of functions right?

Comment: We are not limiting the class of anything, we are exhibiting specific counterexamples to the assertion that $L^p(\mu)\subseteq L^q(\mu)$.  In other words, what you are trying to prove is false without the assumption of finiteness for $\mu$.

Comment: I see, so without the finite measure assumption we cannot have: $L^{p}\left(\mu\right)\subset L^{q}\left(\mu\right)$